# How can I click on an href within an <a> tag using Selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm attempting to click on a hyperlink ( tag) on a webpage using Selenium, but I'm only finding older solutions that no longer work or are based on outdated versions. Can anyone show me a current method to click on an href attribute within an  tag using Selenium?

highest_version_element.get_attribute("innerHTML") returns

```html
<a
  class="c-archiveSearchListItem__link"
  href="https://game8.co/games/Genshin-Impact/archives/440922"
  ><p class="c-archiveSearchListItem__title">
    4.4 Redeem Codes List and Rewards
  </p>
  <p class="c-archiveSearchListItem__description">
    Here is the list of all Genshin Impact 4.4 Redeem Codes, including the
    limited-time livestrea...
  </p>
  <p class="c-archiveSearchListItem__date">01/28/2024 8:14 PM</p></a
>
```

I've attempted to access an href attribute within an  tag using this function

```
continue_link = highest_version_element.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, '4.4 Redeem')
```

The resulting continue_link variable contains text within

tags but lacks an  tag with an href attribute. Here's an example of the structure:

```html
<p class="c-archiveSearchListItem__title">4.4 Redeem Codes List and Rewards</p>
<p class="c-archiveSearchListItem__description">
  Here is the list of all Genshin Impact 4.4 Redeem Codes, including the
  limited-time livestrea...
</p>
<p class="c-archiveSearchListItem__date">01/28/2024 8:14 PM</p>
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

## Solutions

1. Using the XPATH to get the link.

```py
element = highest_version_element.find_element(By.XPATH, '//a[contains(@href, "440922")]')
element.click()
```

2. Using the class name to get the link.

```py
element = highest_version_element.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"c-archiveSearchListItem__link")
element.click()
```

Comment: Use a XPath expression/method. It's not outdated. Very simple task

Comment: XPATH of:  //a[contains(@href, "440922")] oughta do it.  No need for highest_version_element reference... but if you need frist link inside that, maybe : highest_version_element.find_element(By.XPATH, "/a").click()

Comment: @browsermator 
Thank you for the response. I tried without XPath because I'm not very familiar with it since this is my first scraper. But I guess I'll have to take a closer look at it. Thanks anyway for your helpful response.